# PHPでXdebugを利用したデバッグがブレークポイントに止まらない

Tags: php, vscode, wordpress, debugging

**環境**
PHP Version :8.1.9
Xdebug version :3.1.5
IDE : Visual Studio Code 1.74.0
サーバー：Local　(旧名：Local By FlyWheel）

**やりたいこと**
WordPressの自作テーマの開発中にPHPのデバッグを利用したい。
使用しているVisualStudioで固定ページのpage-○○.phpなどの適当なコードにブレークポイントを設定して動作を確認することが目的となっています。

**やったこと**
VSCodeの拡張機能からPHPdebugをインストール済み
LocalのアドオンからXdebug + VS Codeを選択しインストール済み
インストール後　publicフォルダ下に.vscodeというフォルダが作成され、その中にlaunch.jsonが作成されました。
launch.jsonに"pathMappings"を加えた。

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug 3.0 (Local)",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_children": 128,
                "max_data": 1024,
                "max_depth": 3,
                "show_hidden": 1
            },
            "pathMappings": {
                "${workspaceRoot}": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug (Local)",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_children": 128,
                "max_data": 1024,
                "max_depth": 3,
                "show_hidden": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000,
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_children": 128,
                "max_data": 1024,
                "max_depth": 3,
                "show_hidden": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

その後、デバッグを
Listen for Xdebug 3.0 (Local)を選択し、ブレークポイントを設定し実行。
現状としてブレークポイントを設定したphpのページにアクセスしても何も起こらず表示されている。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もし似たような原因があれば教えていただけると幸いです。
初質問なため情報が不足してる等あれば教えていただけると助かります。